# What do features ±F and ±N mean?

Tags: syntax, nouns, adverbs

Could anybody please help me understand what the [±F] and [±N] features mean? What do they stand for, I have no idea .... (The article elucidates in terms of GB theory)

> Given these observations, then, and recalling that bare-NP adverbs are
>   headed by a particular class of common nouns, I suggest that
>   Case-assignment in bare-NP adverbs occurs through a special feature,
>   **[+F]**, which is borne by these nouns. This feature is inherited by any
>   NP having such an N as its head, and it assigns an Oblique Case to the
>   NP it labels: [...] (Larson, R. K. (1985). Bare-NP adverbs. Linguistic
>   inquiry, 16(4), 595-621.)
>
> Receiving Case inherently or not needing Case at all, these items are
>   not obliged to occur adjacent to some **[-N]** or [+Tense] governing
>   element; hence, within VP, for example, bare-NP adverbs will freely
>   reorder with other "Case-independent" categories like PP and S': [...]
>   (Larson, R. K. (1985). Bare-NP adverbs. Linguistic inquiry, 16(4),
>   595-621.)

Comment: Reads to me like the F in [+F] just means _Feature_. Nothing else from the quoted paragraph seems obvious, at least.

Comment: As Janus noted [+F] means a Feature, a Formal (syntactic) feature which is assigned to a noun in the lexicon. [+F] is a general label, it could stand for [+oblique]/[+dative], etc. The other feature [+N] is a categorial feature, nouns are [+N/-V], verbs are [-N/+V].

Comment: I think the term _elucidates_ is not perhaps the best description of what's going on.

Comment: Good, I will plug in the meanings as I read on. @jlawler You're probably right about 'elucidates' not being the best description because the paper is half-baked to some.

Comment: The paper itself is fine; it was published in *Linguistic Inquiry*, so it assumes a certain *basic* familiarity with generative syntax.

Comment: I read further literature from its bibliography, and other authors construe it as a specific feature unbeknown to the academics that are inherent throughout the nouns. Thanks for your help, all.